# How to show user login name on the next page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a login as my first screen when you open the applications. I have 10 more pages after you logged in. All I want is the name of that person who logged-in in all pages across like, (Welcome, User!). I have no idea on how to do this

here is my code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtUsername.IsEnabled = true;
    txtPassword.IsEnabled = true;
    txtMessage.Text = "";
    txtMessage.IsEnabled = false;

    try
    {
        SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("Select  * from register where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPassword.Password + "'", oConnection);

        if (oConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            oConnection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataReader reader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        string Username = null;

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            username = txtUsername.Text;
            oConnection.Close();

            NavigationService _Nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
            _Nav.Navigate(new Uri("Menuxaml.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else if (txtUsername.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Username";
        else if (txtPassword.Password.Trim().Length == 0)
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Password";
        else
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Invalid Username or Password!";
            txtPassword.Password = "";
            txtUsername.Text = "";
        }

        oConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are developing in WPF?

Comment: yes i am developing in WPF

Comment: Is your project has Master page structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the username in all the 10 pages, I would suggest you to add this in Application resources and access this from all over the application.

Let me show you how to do this.

```
   Application.Current.Resources.Add("UserName",txtUsername.Text);
```

and then on your second page use this resource to set your label.

```
lbl.Content = Application.Current.Resources["UserName"];
```

Comment: @XAMLLearner below number zero at left hand side you can find the correct symbol just click it...thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to the second page either by the constructor or public method exposed by the second page.

Here's the detail:

Page1:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page2 p = new Page2(2);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(p);
    }
}
```

Page2:

```
public partial class Page2 : Page
{
    int valueFromPage1;
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Page2(int val):this()
    {
        valueFromPage1 = val;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page2_Loaded);

    }
    void Page2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Content = "Value passed from page1 is: " + valueFromPage1;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any further problem.

If you want to use the same structure then

```
page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Page.xaml?parameter=test", UriKind.Relative));
```

Destination page:

```
   string parameter = string.Empty;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", out parameter)) 
{
        this.label.Text = parameter;
    }
```

Comment: must i change the way i navigated to another page? look at my coding

Comment: I didn't get it working..Thanks for your help. i have used example from jadavparesh06 and works fine.